# How to move Ubuntu GUI application (with Chrome) to Ubuntu server

Tags: server, ssh, google-chrome, gui

I have workable GUI application with Chrome (special parser), what need to working very long time with intensive I/O. We decide to move this application to Hetzner VPS, but it support only Ubuntu server with SSH, if I have right understand. How I can do this deployment? Locally I have last version Ubuntu and last version of Windows.

Comment: You don't. Chrome needs a desktop. Recode your application to without a browser so you can run it command line and your server can deal with it. Or recode it so your chrome desktop serves the server the gui app data part you need and have the server return the results when done. Chrome itself on a  VPS won't work. Then you'd need a - VPS with a  desktop not a VPS with just a server.

Comment: @Rinzwind, thank you.

Comment: If your application needs Chrome, but is not interactive and can run unattended, you can install Xdummy, a "dummy X server". It simulates a display which GUI applications can use, but it's just similar to `/dev/null` device, there isn't any real display, the output goes nowhere. It is specifically meant for running unattended GUI applications on servers.

Comment: There's also an option to tunnel X Window over SSH connection, then the application can run on the server but display the window and be controlled from your local X display on your Linux desktop.

Comment: @raj, Interesting, thank you. will try. And one more question, please. If, for example, I will found dataCenter with preinstalled Ubuntu with GUI, is Chrome will be working with disconnected desktop? So, I can connect to desktop by VNC for example, or TigerVNC, than I'll disconnected my desktop. What will doing Chrome after that? Will parser based on Chrome be aborted or still will be working? User interaction for my special parser is not needed (except Google Recapture for starting), but all functions based on workable Chrome with desktop. What will be when desktop disappear?

Comment: @raj, tunnel X Window over SSH I don't understand how it will working. Parser working a couple month and getting about 10 millions of pages for something site, it's a reason when parser is impossible to run on home computer. I want to turn off my home computer and parser on server need to continue working. This is a goal.

Comment: There are two different "sides" of desktop in X Window System. From the application point of view, "desktop" is just some logical resource that enables applications to run the GUI. It doesn't need to be actually displayed anywhere. From the other side, from user's point of view, that logical desktop may be connected to physical graphics card, to VNC server, to a (logical) display on another machine over the network (the case of SSH tunneling goes here) or nowhere at all (a "dummy" desktop). (cont'd in next comment)

Comment: As for your question about VNC, VNC server can be configured - and it's quite common - to keep persistent sessions, ie. if you disconnect, your session is still running. You should think of desktop being "inside" the VNC server, if you connect to it via the VNC client you're just viewing the desktop remotely, but when you disconnect the desktop still exists "within" the VNC server.

Comment: Thank you, @raj I understand (1) I need full Ubuntu with GUI, not only server. (2) VNC connect no matter to working Chrome, I can disconnect GUI at any time. (3) I can use SSH redirect to my local computer than disconnect and application with Chrome will continue working. (4) I can try to use  dummy X server, if interaction don't need for my application with Chrome. Is it correct?

Comment: As for 3) not. Your local machine in that case is the actual display for the applications running on server, if you disconnect they will have no display, so they will probably abort. Other points are correct.

Comment: @raj, thank you